# Why London force dominates in Alkyl Halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, dipole

**Why London Force is greater than dipole-dipole interactions in Alkyl Halides?**

> [image]

As we know that most of the time London force is weaker than other forces. Then why in this case it's not so?

According to me, due to high charge separation (in C & X) the dipole-dipole interaction must me stronger than the London force which depends more on the surface area of molecules.

Source:[Leroy G.Wade Organic chemistry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1292151102)

Comment: That depends on halide, for bromides and iodides textbook is totally right. For chlorides and fluorides that somewhat depends,

Comment: @scientist omega please refer ro this http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/vlu_organik/substitution/alkylhalogenide/einfuehrung.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/12/oc/substitution/alkylhalogenide/eigenschaften_der_halogenalkane/eigenschaften.vscml.html

Comment: Actually size of halogen is so big that it kind of shields C atoms which makes it harder for dipole dipole interaction.Plus large surface area increases London force.